# In telebot @bot.message_handler() running even if it is kept inside a if statement

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-decorators

I am relatively new to coding and to python. I am trying to make a telegram bot using telebot.
I have a flow in which I have to go. eg: after /start, I should get a text. So I created a running_work_list in which my workflow is arranged in order and after completion, I delete the index 0 elements. 'start' is the first element in the array.
So I tried to implement something like this so that I can comfortably code each step rather than looking at input and deciding.

But despite putting inside an if statement,  '@bot.message_handler()'  is running even if the condition fails.

```
    if running_work_list[0]=='start':
        print('inside if')
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['start','new test'])
        def start(message):
            print('user sent start')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,welcome_message)
            running_work_list.pop(0)
            print(f'work flow deciding list {running_work_list}')
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text','photo','poll'])
        def bot_intro(message):
            print('here')
            print(f'user sent {message.text}')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,BOT_INTRO_MSG)
```

Below are the outputs I got. The user had sent /start first and then some other random text.

```
    inside if
    user sent start
    work flow deciding list ['test_name', 'test_description', 'test_time', 'test_image', 'test_poll']
    here
    user sent fdf
```

Is it like the '@bot.message_handler()' will run even if we put it inside an if statement?

Comment: Perhaps you have problems with spacing. Python is really sensitive to spaces and tabs. Check if you have 4 spaces everywhere. At least I see issue for `bot_intro` method

Comment: Hi @wowkin2. Thanks for pointing that 4 spacing in this question out. But that happened when I copy-pasted the code to here and it's all okay in my code. I'll edit and correct that error in the question. My bad. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing `@bot.message_handler` decorator marks the function to be called when the message matches the filters that you've passed as arguments (`content_types` or `commands`). They are called by the `telebot` library directly and do not execute the `if` statement after they have been registered.

The proper way to do this is to invert the logic: define the message handler functions at the top level of the program and decide what you should do in the `if` within the function.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew Morozko. I found the register_next_step_handler method which is very helpful in implementing step by step process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927835/how-to-use-telebot-module-to-create-an-inline-button-in-bot-window-which-if-cli
Could you please look into this question as well? I'm stuck here with this problem. Thanks in advance