# lamda funtion in @bot.message_handler() not working properly in telebot python

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried to implement the following line of code in python script for a telegram bot building using telebot.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg:True if msg.text.startswith('/test'))
def test_start(message):
    msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'This feature is under developement')
```

Above code gives me a syntax error.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg:True if msg.text.startswith('/test') else False)
def test_start(message):
    msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'This feature is under developement')
```

This code solves the syntax error, but still, it doesn't do what I want it to do. When a user sends '/test some text' I want to identify this and do some actions after that.

I am relatively new to python and this is my first time using telebot and lambda functions. So please help me in

1. identifying why the 1st code gave me a syntax error.
2. How to implement this startswith('/test') properly.
   Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ternary operator has a specific syntax, that has to be followed:

```
<value if True> if <condition> else <value if False>
```

What you did in the first sample is:

```
<value if True> if <condition>
```

Also you don't have to do it like you did

```
True if msg.text.startswith('/test') else False
```

`.startswith()` returns `bool` on its own.

It's unclear what decorator does, but why don't you just perform the check inside of the function?

```
@bot.message_handler
def test_start(message):
    if msg.startswith('/test'):
        msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'This is feature is under developement')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like that:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: True == msg.text.startswith("/test"))
def starts_with_test(message):
    args = message.text.split(' ');
    for arg in args:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "arg = " + arg)
```

It will handle only commands that started with "/test". Then you can use split(' ') to parce arguments. For some types of fields there can be limitaions. For example for "InlineKeyboardButton"->"callback_data" field. It can be <= 64 bytes. Another handlers will work as intended.